# Excel Wildcard If statement for two columns?

Tags: excel, if-statement, wildcard, vlookup, data-analysis

I'm not sure what excel function to use.

I have two columns 'asset tag' and 'computer name'. Both unique values. The asset tag has a name like '11111' the computer name has a name like 'AA-11111-BB'.

I need a formula to output every asset that is also in the computer name column into its own column.

As you see the asset tags name is inside the computer name between characters.

I don't know how to tie these two columns together when their names are not exactly the same.

IS the a wildcard if statement formula for two columns to accomplish this. Please see my screenshot as well.

[image: Screenshot of spreadsheet]

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: 2016 Pro Version

Comment: I think Im just going to do this the long way. The problem Im having is the fact the column b has the column A value located between dashes. I will find a formula to extract betweeen dashes and then us an if statement to match the columns hopefully that works.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work if you will always have 5 numbers for PC name and it will either be in the middle or at the end of the string.

Have this formula reference the first computer name cell:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(RIGHT(B1,2)),RIGHT(B1,5),VALUE(MID(B1,4,5)))
```

(this will return the Asset tag without all the extra characters)

Then to match them, you can do a vlookup to return the asset class (column P in example below is the same cell as referenced above, column A is your asset class number).

```
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,P1:P3,1,0),"")
```

This may require some clean up if you have duplicates, but this should get you started.